# Flutter Persistant Bottom Navigation Package - Appbar height error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[after using a safe area to scaffold-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImZcb.png)

I am using [persistent_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) this package for keeping Bottonavigation for all screens but the height of the appbar has changed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hABko.png)

Here is my code. I have wrapped Scaffold using `SafeArea`it works fine after adding the safearea but it showing some white spaces at the top of the appbar.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:newmart/Order/order.dart';
import 'package:newmart/Screens/dashboard.dart';
import 'package:newmart/Recharge/recharge.dart';
import 'package:newmart/Company/support.dart';
import 'package:newmart/Screens/wallet.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/persistent_tab_view.dart';
// ignore: unused_import
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import '../widgets/floating_cart_total.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
const HomePage({super.key, required this.mobileNumber});
final String mobileNumber;
@override
State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
String mb = "";

final PersistentTabController _controller =
    PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
}

final int _selectedIndex = 0;
// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
int Index = 0;

List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
  return [
    const Dashboard(),
    const Order(),
    const Wallet(),
    const Recharge(),
    const Support(),
  ];
}

List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
  return [
    PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
      icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.home),
      title: ("Home"),
      activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
      inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
    ),
    PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_bag_outlined),
      title: ("Order"),
      activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
      inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
    ),
    PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.wallet),
      title: ("Wallet"),
      activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
      inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
    ),
    PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.charging_station),
      title: ("Recharge"),
      activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
      inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
    ),
    PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.support_agent),
      title: ("Support"),
      activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
      inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
    ),
  ];
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: const TotalCartCount(),
        bottomNavigationBar: PersistentTabView(
          context,
          // bottomScreenMargin: 0,
          // margin: top,
          controller: _controller,
          screens: _buildScreens(),
          items: _navBarsItems(),
          confineInSafeArea: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white, // Default is Colors.white.
          handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true, // Default is true.
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset:
              true, // This needs to be true if you want to move up the screen when keyboard appears. Default is true.
          stateManagement: true, // Default is true.
          hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows:
              true, // Recommended to set 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset' as true while using this argument. Default is true.
          decoration: NavBarDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            colorBehindNavBar: Colors.white,
          ),
          popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
          popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
          itemAnimationProperties: const ItemAnimationProperties(
            // Navigation Bar's items animation properties.
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            curve: Curves.ease,
          ),
          screenTransitionAnimation: const ScreenTransitionAnimation(
            // Screen transition animation on change of selected tab.
            animateTabTransition: true,
            curve: Curves.ease,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          ),
          navBarStyle: NavBarStyle
              .style1, // Choose the nav bar style with this property.
        )),
  );
}
}
```

Comment: Please include some code of what you built in your question to make the answer more relevant

Comment: I just copy and paste the documentation of the https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar package to my code and the bottom navigation working well.....but my app bar size changes.. ...

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your app bar using the SafeArea widget?

Comment: @pranalikumbhar just try to Wrap your `Scaffold()` with `SafeArea()` widget

Comment: I have updated my question Sir...after wrapping the scaffold into a safe area...Please check

Comment: @pranalikumbhar Can you include your full code I think you write wrong code.

Comment: Yes sir. I have updated my question. please review it. @RavindraS.Patil

Comment: @pranalikumbhar Where is your `Appbar` widget in your code? Please don't need to call Sir

Comment: @pranalikumbhar please go through [example](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar/example) and see the `AppBar` declaration if you dont understand please let me know

Comment: I have added an App bar to each _navBarsItems screen.